# Qual a referencia para HttpContext.GetOwinContext() ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, owin

Precisei abstrair os `Controllers` de uma aplicação `ASP.NET MVC` para uma `Class Library` porque estou utilizando tecnologias diferentes na mesma aplicação.

Porém, estou com o erro:

> 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já instalei o `System.Web.Mvc` e `System.Web`

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Modularizacao.Comum.App_Start;
```

Mas não resolveu esta dependencia. O que falta referenciar para não acontecer este erro ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Nenhuma**.

**`HttpContext.GetOwinContext()`** é um método de extensão em `System.Net.Http`.

Possivelmente falta o [pacote **Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/), ele que contém essa extensão.

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

Comment: Thanks, works fine!